# Can't view local images with apache

Tags: php, apache

I'm on mac osx10.6.8.  I'm using XAMPP.  I'm running all my script through firefox by typing in localhost/index.php etc.  All the scripts run, and everything I've written so far works fine.

Right now, I'm able to browse my folders and upload images.  It will successfully save and rename an image and store it in my htdocs folder.  The problem is when I try to display the image that was just saved.

I have the following code:

```
<img src="file:///applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Images/1921304523pvyNZ.jpg">
```

If I type in `file:///applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Images/1921304523pvyNZ.jpg` in the address bar, the picture comes up.  But when I try to use img src, just a broken image shows up.  When I click on get info for that broken image, it gives me the exact address and even displays the image in "media preview."  Why, then won't it display it in the website?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `file://`, use `http://localhost/path/to/image/` .. then the images will be served through xampp rather than from the filesystem. I expect this is a security feature of your browser, not to mix filesystem and http-served content.

In your case, you probably want `http://localhost/Images/1921304523pvyNZ.jpg`

Also, make sure 'Images' does indeed have an upper case 'I'. No big deal on OSX but will be if you deploy on a Linux/UNIX server.

As Fabricio points out, you can/should reference the images relatively, and keep your web application easy to deploy. So if you are displaying `http://localhost/index.php`, the image path is just `Images/xxxx.jpg`.

Comment: I used the second one you suggested.  And yes, now it works.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Referencing the images relatively should prevent that error as well.

Comment: @user1416658 if this solved your problem, please mark my answer as accepted using the green tick mark. Welcome to SO :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.  I found the problem by looking at my Xampp error log.  For some reason my images file permissions were very limited.  -rx------...  I just changed the file permission to allow all users to be able to read those files.  Just a note in my opinion since I am lazy, others will probably disagree, you can give them full permission if it is on your own computer, i.e. 777.  But in best practice you should only give the files the permissions that are needed for security reasons...

Since you are using a Mac you can use the `chmod` command to do this in terminal.
go to the file directory in terminal.
`cd /Applications/XAMP/xamppfiles/htdocs/.../images/`

then type in 
`chmod 644 yourfilename.extension`

you can confirm that is was changed by using `ls -l`

644 should give you `-rw-r--r--` This should be pretty secure.